# Threading - Do similar threading without async

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, asynchronous

I was trying to do a sample threading program, where the spawning of thread is in a while loop. I DO NOT want to generate multiple number of threads. The while loop should keep on running, irrespective of whether the thread completed execution or not. There is a call to the .get() function of the above thread within the while loop. Again, this has to be called only when the thread executed correctly.

My code is given below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

int thread(int varJ)
{
    std::cout<<"\t\t"<<varJ<<std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    return varJ;  
}

int main()
{
    int varI = 0;
    std::future<int> future = std::async(std::launch::async, [](){return 0;});
    std::future_status status;
    bool flag = false;

    while(1)
    {
        status = future.wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(0));
        if(status == std::future_status::ready && !flag)
        {
            future = std::async(std::launch::async, thread, varI);
            flag = true;
        }
        status = future.wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(0));
        if(status == std::future_status::ready && flag)
        {
            std::cout << "\t result is " << future.get() << '\n';
            future = std::async(std::launch::async, [](){return 0;});
            flag = false;
        }
        varI++;
    }
}
```

The output obtained:

```
    0
 result is 0
    865
 result is 865
    1723
 result is 1723
    2632
 result is 2632
    3590
 result is 3590
    4551
 result is 4551
    5509
 result is 5509
```

The output is as I expected it to be. 
Now, consider the fact that the function call that is made inside the thread is from another library that has dependencies on boost libraries and cuda libraries and leads to some unknown bug in the code that makes it to crash. That being a call to a 3rd party library, I do not want to end up trying to fix that bug, but would like to explore other options than async.

What different approaches could be brought in for the code to exhibit the same output that I get using async in the above mentioned code. Using boost::thread and p_thread are two options, but I am nowhere near to getting a code similar to this program working using any of those methods.

Comment: This probably belongs to [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I don't see a need for the double checking, the flag, or the empty (lambda) async? [Seems to give the expected output](http://ideone.com/KQCL5B) without it?

Comment: Updated the question to be present in SO.